# MongoDB: How to connect to different database with same connection?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I want to connect to a different database with Mongo::Client object as we do in command `use database`.

I was trying with `db = client.db(database)`, but it is giving me `undefined method 'db' for #<Mongo::Client:0x29473968 cluster=127.0.0.1:27017> (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through API, I found that it's [use](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Client.html#use-instance_method) method.